# Mutex granularity

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a question regarding threads. It is known that basically when we call for mutex(lock) that means that thread keeps on executing the part of code uninterrupted by other threads until it meets mutex(unlock). (At least that's what they say in the book) So my question is if it is actually possible to have several scoped WriteLocks which do not interfere with each other. For example something like this:

If I have a buffer with N elements without any new elements coming, however with high frequency updates (like change value of Kth element) is it possible to set a different lock on each element so that the only time threads would stall and wait is if actually 2 or more threads are trying to update the same element?

Comment: Why wouldn't that work?

Comment: Your actual question has nothing to do with "scoped locks" mentioned in the title.  Scoped locks take a mutex and lock it and unlock the mutex when they are destroyed (normally when going out of scope).

Comment: @stefaanv is right. Please change the title to something more descriptive.

Comment: I took a shot at providing a more matching title. Feel free to come up with a better one (and please leave tags like "C++" out of titles, that's what tags are for).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, English is not my native language. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question about N mutexes: yes, that is indeed possible. What resources are protected by a mutex depends entirely on you as the user of that mutex.

This leads to the first (statement) part of your question. A mutex by itself does not guarantee that a thread will work uninterrupted. All it guarantees is MUTual EXclusion - if thread B attempts to lock a mutex which thread A has locked, thread B will block (execute no code) until thread A unlocks the mutex.

This means mutexes *can be used* to guarantee that a thread executes a block of code uninterrupted; but this works only if *all* threads follow the same mutex-locking protocol around that block of code. Which means it is your responsibility to assign semantics (or meaning) to each individual mutex, and correctly adhere to those semantics in your code.

If you decide for the semantics to be "I have an array `a` of N data elements and an array `m` of N mutexes, and accessing `a[i]` can only be done when `m[i]` is locked," then that's how it will work.

The need to consistently stick to the same protocol is why you should generally encapsulate the mutex and the code/data protected by it in a class in some way or another, so that outside code doesn't need to know the details of the protocol. It just knows "call this member function, and the synchronisation will happen automagically." This "automagic" will be the class correcrtly implementing the protocol.

Comment: Thank You. I do indeed encapsulate locks in my `Element` class, however I also have a small follow-up question - let's say I have a `buffer` but now with small chance of insert operation, and as far as I understand I need to lock the entire `buffer` for insert operation since it affects the data structure used for the entire `buffer`. But if I in fact have an on-going `update` operation, will the buffer lock actually notice it or it will have a run-time error?

Comment: @ConstantineSamoilenko Sounds like you could use a read/write lock for the buffer in addition to a mutex for each element. Locking the mutex would require acquiring a read lock first. Insertion would require acquiring a write lock. That way, insertion can only happen when no mutex is locked.

Answer (score 4):

A crucial consideration when deciding between a mutex per array and a mutex per element is whether there are operations - like tracking the number of "in-use" array elements, the "active" element, or moving a pointer-to-array to a larger buffer - that can only be done safely by one thread while all the others are blocked.

A lesser but sometimes important consideration is the amount of extra memory more mutexes use.

If you genuinely need to do this kind of update as quickly as possible in a highly contested multi-threaded program, you may also want to learn about lock-free atomic types and their compare-and-swap / exchange operations, but I'd recommend against considering that unless profiling the existing locking is significant in your overall program performance.

Answer (score 1):

A mutex does not stop other threads from running completely, it only stops other threads from locking the same mutex. I.e. while one thread is keeping the mutex locked, the operating system continues to do context switches letting other threads run also, but if any other thread is trying to lock the same mutex its execution will be halted until the mutex is unlocked.

So yes, you can indeed have several different mutexes and lock/unlock them independently. Just beware of deadlocks, i.e. if one thread can lock more than one mutex at a time you can run into a situation where thread 1 has locked mutex A and is trying to lock mutex B but blocks because thread 2 already has mutex B locked and it is trying to lock mutex A..

Answer (score 0):

Its not completely clear that your use case is:

1. the threads gets a buffer assigned on that they have to work
2. the threads have some results and request a special buffer to update.

On the first variant you need some assignment logic that assigns a buffer to a thread. 
This logic has to be exectued in an atomic way. so the best is to use a mutex to protect the assignment logic.

On the other variant it may be the best to have a vector of mutexes, one for each buffer element.

In Both cases the buffer does not need a protection because it (or better each field of it) is only accessed from one thread at a time.

You also may inform yourself about 'semaphores'. These contain a counter that allows to manage ressources that have a limited amount but more than one. Mutexes are a special case of semaphores with n=1.

Comment: Mutexes and binary semaphores have similar usage, but they are not the same.  explaining mutexes as special case of semaphores is only meaningful because semaphores are older, so learning semaphores just to understand mutexes is overkill.  Also a lot of situations that were handled with semaphores can now be done more clearly with condition variables (which take a mutex, not a binary semaphore).

Answer (score 0):

You can have mutex per entry, C++11 mutex can be easily converted into an adaptive-spinlock, so you can achieve good CPU/Latency tradeoff.

Or, if you need very low latency yet have enough CPUs you can use an atomic "busy" flag per entry and spin in a tight compare-exchange loop on contention.

From experience, though,  the best performance and scalability are achieved when concurrent writes are serialized via a command queue (or a queue of smaller immutable buffers to be concatenated at destination) and a *single* thread processing the queue.